# Rails link_to open a larger image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app showing thumbnails, but if I click the thumbail, its downloaded, not showed up. How its work? link_to image_tag('lorem'), image_tag('lorem_big')?

```
<% for photo in @article.attachments %>
  <%= link_to image_tag('dinamic/'+photo.id.to_s+'/'+'thumbs_'+photo.image_file_name), "#{request.env["HTTP_HOST"]}/public/images/dinamic/"+photo.id.to_s+"/"+"originals_"+photo.image_file_name, :class => 'single_image'%>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <% for photo in @static.attachments %>
  <a id="single_image" href="<%=  image_path("dinamic/"+photo.id.to_s+"/"+"originals_"+photo.image_file_name) %>" > <%= image_tag('dinamic/'+photo.id.to_s+'/'+'thumbs_'+photo.image_file_name) %> </a>
<% end %>
```

Image_path solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different browsers?

Try to capture HTTP communication how your app server sets Content-Disposition header attribute.

If you cannot control your server, you can do minicontroller which will render one  tag with that image :)